# DNS server with scripting

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, scripting, dns-server

I would like to know if there's any way of having a DNS server on Linux that runs a script and reply a different IP list depending on the script data returned.

I've searched Google for 'DNS server with scripting' but found nothing.

EDIT: I wanted to return a different IP list depending of the request IP and found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774490/dns-resolving-based-on-client-ip and @Rex told me about GeoDNS.

I leave this open just in case someone has the 'DNS scripting' answer, for others to know.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Return the IP sorted by distance to the country of the request, @Rex but I've just found a reply. Going to add it as an answer.

Comment: Something like GeoDNS would come to mind for that

Comment: That's perfect! Better than the other solutions. Thank you @Rex :-)

Comment: Why downvote? Ninja downvoter, you know that constructive comments helps to improve, don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com) includes the ability to be extended or use various backends for data.  One option is the "[pipe](http://doc.powerdns.com/backends-detail.html)" which will retrieve the DNS data from an external binary of your choosing.

Comment: Oh fine. In the other reply I saw that but I thought that it was only to geoip requests. Thanx.